# Is two-factor authentication required to upload iOS app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Today I wanted to upload a new version of iOS app to App Store via Xcode, but it shows me the error:

"Two-factor authentication must be turned on for your Apple ID. After you turn it on, signing in to your developer account will require both your password and access to your trusted devices or trusted phone number."

Previously (even yesterday) everything worked just fine without 2FA, so is there anything that could be done without 2FA?

Comment: you are mixing a few things together – 2-factor authentication is for logging in the developer portal; not for the apps/contents you'd intend to upload/create.

Comment: ... and you should have been getting loads of emails about it for the past few weeks - I know I have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an effort to keep your account more secure, two-factor authentication will be required to sign in to your Apple Developer account and Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles starting February 27, 2019. This extra layer of security for your Apple ID helps ensure that you're the only person who can access your account.

Please refer the below link

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204915

Answer (score 5):

I face same issue, but we can export the ipa file instead of directly uploading from Xcode and then upload ipa file via application loader. It worked for me.